# How do I switch to Sculpting mode?

Tags: sculpting

I have my model selected, and I click "Sculpting" in the upper menu.
However, "Sculpting" is not possible, only "Object", "Edit" and "Pose".

What do I have to do to go to Sculpting Mode?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: you have selected the armature, not the character object, you need to come back to object mode to be able to select the object, then switch to sculpt mode

Comment: @moonboots In my answer, I have added info about having to switch to Object Mode first. I have also added a video that shows what I had to do. Do you think it's a bug that one has to switch to Object mode first before he can select Sculpting Mode?

Comment: No it's the way it works, you need to go out of the armature modes before being able to have access to the object modes. That said, if in the header menu > Edit > you udisable the Lock Object Mode, you can be in armature's Pose mode, shift select the character object and switch it to Sculpt mode

Answer (score 2):

I had to manually left-click to select the model, not the armature.

Also, I had to switch to Object Mode first. Here is a video of my workflow:

[Workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBMczpdKeHQ)

[image]